# Asynchronous calling and passing values to fragments before setting ViewPager adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I am having a SlideTabLayout in my MainActivity class.I am performing Async network operations in the activity and passing the fetched result to the desired fragments in the SlideTabLayout.But the adapter is setting the fragments with null value and my network operation is fetching data later because of that I am unable to pass the values to the fragments.If you can see the code below.The ArrayList values are 0 at the initial stage and the Activity is passing the null value to all fragments.Then after sometime the ArrayList values are getting updated which are not passed to the fragments.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_meat);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    CatalogueService catalogueService = App42API.buildCatalogueService();
    Intent categoryIntent = getIntent();
    catalogueName = categoryIntent.getStringExtra("CATALOGUE");
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_meat);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_meat);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MeatActivity.this,CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    String chickenCategoryName = "Chicken";
    catalogueService.getItemsByCategory(catalogueName, chickenCategoryName, new App42CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            Catalogue catalogue = (Catalogue) o;
            for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                String category = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getName();
                if (category.equals("Chicken")) {
                    chickenList = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getItemList();
                }
            }
            Log.e("Chicken Size 1",String.valueOf(chickenList.size()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {

            final String error = e.getMessage();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MeatActivity.this,error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    String muttonCategoryName = "Mutton";
    catalogueService.getItemsByCategory(catalogueName, muttonCategoryName, new App42CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            Catalogue catalogue = (Catalogue) o;
            for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                String category = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getName();
                if (category.equals("Mutton")) {
                    muttonList = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getItemList();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MeatActivity.this,"Unable to fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    String seaFoodName = "Sea Foods";
    catalogueService.getItemsByCategory(catalogueName, seaFoodName, new App42CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
            Catalogue catalogue = (Catalogue) o;
            for (int i = 0; i < catalogue.getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                String category = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getName();
                if (category.equals("Sea Foods")) {
                    seaFoodList = catalogue.getCategoryList().get(i).getItemList();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {

        }
    });

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(activityId, chickenList), "CHICKEN");
    Log.e("Chicken Size 2",String.valueOf(chickenList.size()));
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(activityId,muttonList), "MUTTON");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(activityId,seaFoodList), "SEAFOODS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is you are making asynchronous network calls.
do something like this -

declare a class level variable counter 
int counter;

Now in each of the three onSuccess() methods, just do

```
counter ++;
setupViewPager();
```

add a check in your setupViewPager method

```
setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    if(counter == 3){
        // your code to set the adapter
    }
}
```